# Any (Flash?) website to execute a single ping (from PS3 web browser)?

Tags: networking, browser, ping, ps3

I'm trying to do some diagnostics on my PS3's wireless network adapter, but it doesn't seem to have a command prompt or anything from which I can execute a ping.

So, I'm looking for a website with a Flash applet (or similar, but no Java, since that isn't supported) that implements ping or tracert and possibly other network utilities.

I want to execute a ping to the router. I think random lag spikes occurring, which is causing games to drop. I imagine this is due to the wireless connection between PS3 and router, but it's hard to say without any numbers. I also don't have physical access to the router.
I'd also like to compare how Wireless N on PS3 compares to Wireless B/G, so the more tools, the better.

Pingtest.net doesn't cut it, because it averages out the results (ie, I can't tell if spikes are occurring).

Perhaps I'll need to write a Flash applet myself and host it somehow (apache?).

thanks

Comment: Possibly relevant [so] question (especially the not accepted answer if you don't want to get too technical): [I need to ping to an network with flash or actionscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907783/i-need-to-ping-to-an-network-with-flash-or-actionscript)

Comment: If you could run Java, I would have recommended [this](http://netalyzr.icsi.berkeley.edu/). Pity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really help with something that runs on the PS3, but, have you thought of just doing it in reverse from another computer on the network?

Find out what the IP of the console is (Look in settings, or do an IP Scan on your entire subnet - http://www.angryip.org/w/Download ), then from Windows, go to a command prompt and type `ping ip.of.the.ps3 -t`

This will do a continuous ping and you should see if there are any dropouts.

Comment: Yep, great idea. Thanks. I managed to get admin access to the router and then got a ping utility for that. From there I can ping the PS3, and also the outside world, which should help me check where the latency is happening. Every few minutes, the latency spikes to 200ms. This could be problematic. :(